# ORACLE ERROR missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem, I don't understand why do I have this error..

The problem is in the creation of the cursor, but i don't understand why he says that missing a right parentesis...

This is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION classementEtudiantSemestre( p_idEtudiant IN Etudiants.idEtudiant%TYPE, p_idSemestre IN Semestres.idSemestre%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS 

CURSOR cur_lesmoys IS (

SELECT DISTINCT moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre)
FROM ETUDIANTS E
JOIN GROUPES G ON G.idGroupe=E.idGroupe
JOIN SEMESTRES S ON G.idPromotion = S.idPromotion
WHERE idSemestre=p_idSemestre
ORDER BY moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre) DESC


);

u_classement NUMBER:=1;

BEGIN

FOR rty_lesmoys IN cur_lesmoys LOOP

IF rty_lesmoyes.moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre)=moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(p_idEtudiant, p_idSemestre) THEN
RETURN u_classement;
ELSE
u_classement := u_classement +1;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

ORACLE ERRORS :

```
3/23    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/31    PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Help me please..

Answer (score 0):

Does this work (i.e. with no brackets and naming the calculated column)?

```
CURSOR cur_lesmoys IS 
SELECT DISTINCT moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre) AS resultCol
FROM ETUDIANTS E
JOIN GROUPES G ON G.idGroupe=E.idGroupe
JOIN SEMESTRES S ON G.idPromotion = S.idPromotion
WHERE idSemestre=p_idSemestre
ORDER BY moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre) DESC
;
```

If it's still not working, make sure this query works, you might have mistyped the name of a table/column

```
SELECT DISTINCT moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre)
FROM ETUDIANTS E
JOIN GROUPES G ON G.idGroupe=E.idGroupe
JOIN SEMESTRES S ON G.idPromotion = S.idPromotion
WHERE idSemestre=p_idSemestre
ORDER BY moyenneEtudiantSemestreAvecAbs(idEtudiant, idSemestre) DESC
```

It's better to focus on the first error, the second one can often be caused by the first and be confusing.